# Automatically generate Google search query

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, url, dynamic, beautifulsoup

I am trying parse HTML data of certain patents to gather information using Python 3.7 and bs4.

*My Problem simplified:*

Given this URL

```
https://patents.google.com/patent/X/en?oq=Y
```

Where:

X = automatically generated string by Google

Y = My user input (a patent number)

and usually: X == Y (some patent number)

I need to get the value of X.

*A more detailed description of my problem:*

For 90% of my queries, there is no problem, as I can simply parse using the following code:

```
patent_number = "EP1000000B1"
paten_url = ("https://patents.google.com/patent/" + patent_number + "/en?oq=" + patent_number)
    r = requests.get(patent_url)
    response = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
```

However, sometimes the query structure varies, for instance:
I try to search for patent number WO198700753A1 using the code above, but I get an 404 Error, because the URL

```
https://patents.google.com/patent/WO198700753A1/en?oq=WO198700753A1
```

does not exist.
This part does not seem to be relevant

```
en?oq=" + patent_number
```

, but the first part is.

Searching Google Patents by hand reveals that Google automatically redirects my query from WO198700753A1 to WO1987000753A1 (another 0 added).

Is there any way to automatically generate my url (the part in the middle), so my program will always find results?
Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: If you know that this is a constant error of adding zero, you can check the status of the request by r.status and if it is 200 (success) , get the content, else make changes to the query by adding another zero and then get the content.  Another way is use selenium to enter the patent number, since it can act like a browser, use bs4 to capture the content.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in most of my cases

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the structure of the link has changed and the `oq` parameter is not needed. The patent number cannot be randomly generated because each patent has its own unique number. If you generated a patent which not exist, then this page does not exist too.